# how to separate cam1,2,3,4,5,6 first images from the list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

```
lst = ['Cam218-10-03_16-05-21-54.jpg',     
       'Cam318-10-03_17-04-21-54.jpg',
       'Cam418-10-03_16-04-21-54.jpg',  
       'Cam218-10-02_16-05-21-54.jpg',
       'Cam318-10-02_17-04-21-54.jpg',  
       'Cam418-10-02_16-04-21-54.jpg',
       'Cam218-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg',  
       'Cam318-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg', 
       'Cam418-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg',  
       'Cam518-10-02_16-04-08-35.jpg',
       'Cam618-10-02_16-04-08-36.jpg',  
       'Cam118-10-02_16-04-09-33.jpg', 
       'Cam218-10-02_16-04-09-33.jpg',  
       'Cam318-10-02_16-04-09-33.jpg', 
       'Cam418-10-02_16-04-09-33.jpg',  
       'Cam518-10-02_16-04-09-33.jpg',
       'Cam618-10-02_16-04-09-33.jpg',  
       'Cam118-10-02_16-04-11-53.jpg', 
       'Cam218-10-02_16-04-11-53.jpg',  
       'Cam318-10-02_16-04-11-53.jpg', 
       'Cam418-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg',  
       'Cam118-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg', 
       'Cam518-10-02_16-04-11-53.jpg',  
       'Cam118-10-02_16-04-11-53.jpg']
```

From this list I want the output:

```
['Cam118-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg',
 'Cam218-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg',
 'Cam318-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg', 
 'Cam418-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg',
 'Cam518-10-02_16-04-08-35.jpg',
 'Cam618-10-02_16-04-08-36.jpg']
```

by using Python. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far

Comment: And please include a clear description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: i have  traied some sort techniques i jjust got only assending and decending order of above list........

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because you removed the lists. Please keep the actual data structures you are using in your post. If you just post strings on separate lines, we can only guess how you have that data stored in your program.

Comment: thaqs it rellay helps

Answer (score 1):

With `itertools.groupby` - O(n*log(n))

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [next(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(lst), key=lambda cam: cam.partition('-')[0])]
['Cam118-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg',
 'Cam218-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg',
 'Cam318-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg',
 'Cam418-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg',
 'Cam518-10-02_16-04-08-35.jpg',
 'Cam618-10-02_16-04-08-36.jpg']
```

With keeping track of duplicates manually (output not sorted, but potentially useful to other readers) - O(n)

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> 
>>> for cam in lst:
...:    model, *_ = cam.partition('-')
...:    if model not in seen:
...:        result.append(cam)
...:        seen.add(model)
...:        
>>> result
['Cam218-10-03_16-05-21-54.jpg',
 'Cam318-10-03_17-04-21-54.jpg',
 'Cam418-10-03_16-04-21-54.jpg',
 'Cam518-10-02_16-04-08-35.jpg',
 'Cam618-10-02_16-04-08-36.jpg',
 'Cam118-10-02_16-04-09-33.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make if condition to check for the occurrence of the photo tag after sorting the list

```
list.sort()
i = 1
for item in list:
    if(item[3]==str(i)):
        i=i+1
        print(item)
        continue
```

the result is

```
Cam118-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg
Cam218-10-02_16-04-08-31.jpg
Cam318-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg
Cam418-10-02_16-04-08-30.jpg
Cam518-10-02_16-04-08-35.jpg
Cam618-10-02_16-04-08-36.jpg
```

if you want to get the first occurrence of item with no regards to its order ascendingly, removing list.sort() shall resolve that.

Comment: thaqs its helpfull

Comment: I think this won't produce the right output if the initial list is ordered differently. For example, if all entries for cam 2 come before cam 1, you will never print any cam with "id" 2.